# xalan and xerces in jboss eap 6.0.1

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm migrating an application from Glassfish 2.1 to Jboss eap 6.0.1. Now I deploy my app in Jboss correctly but it doesn't work. I have made debug and I saw the problem. When the code arrives to this line:

`OutputFormat format = OutputFormat(doc);`

It fails. I made a new watch of **"OutputFormat(doc)"** and in the value appears this: **Unknown type "org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat"<**

This class is inside xerces library. This library is installed as a module in my jboss. I have tried many things:

1.- Exclude jboss library and included the library in my war. **Not deploy.**

2.- Include my library (no JBoss' library) as a new module and, in the manifest, add this line: `Dependencies: myModuleName`. **It deploys, but it doesn't work.**

3.- The before "solution", and exclude jboss library. **Not deploy.**

This ocurred when the code arrives at the following line, and I have tried the same solutions:

`XPathAPI.selectSingleNode( xmlTempDoc,"//a" )`

The error at this time is: **Unknown type "org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI"**

This packages are in xercesImpl-2.9.1 and xalan-2.7.1 libraries respectively.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: have you been able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude the default xalan and xerces libraries that come packaged witn JBoss EAP by adding *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* under */WEB-INF* with below content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>            
        <exclusions>            
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then include yours in some path such as */lib* folder.

Comment: Thanks to response, I understand that you want say <i>jboss-deployment-structure.xml</i>, no? If you want say this, I have tried it already and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, sorry for any mismatch!
Have you included your custom libraries after doing so?
Could you paste what exception you have exactly when you try it?