# org.springframework.ws and Xalan problem on Jboss EAP 6.x

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss-eap-6, xalan

Hello I'm facing problem with Jboss EAP 6.x after update org.springframework.ws - spring-xml

In my project I have use Xalan in version 2.7.2 , now I want to update org.springframework.ws - spring-xml from version 2.4.0 to 2.4.4 and upload wars of my app on Jboss EAP 6.x

While deployment I got error:

> Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported:
>   http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD  at
>   org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571)
>     at
>   __redirected.__TransformerFactory.setAttribute(__TransformerFactory.java:169)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.5.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.defaultSettings(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:56)
>   [spring-xml-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar:]   at
>   org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.newInstance(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:32)
>   [spring-xml-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar:]   at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:58)
>   [spring-ws-core-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar:]   ... 31 more

After fast investigation I have found that in spring-xml version 2.4.4 it's new TransformerFactoryUtils which uses TransformerFactory from same package as Xalan , and it's leads to problem with classloader.

I try to follow solutions from [TransformerFactory and Xalan Dependency Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152707/transformerfactory-and-xalan-dependency-conflict) and [xalan and xerces in jboss eap 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334144/xalan-and-xerces-in-jboss-eap-6-0-1)
but both won't work for me.

I have also found some solution on redhat site : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1410603 but without subscription I don't have access for it...

And one face same issue? Maybe have some solution which may work in this case? Big thanks in advance.

Comment: I also getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue even for **JBoss EAP 7.2**

Since JBoss runs on JDK 6, 7, and 8, that is why the included **Xalan** does not have `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD` support as it was added in **JDK 7**.

You may force JBoss to use *TransformerFactory* from Oracle JDK 8. Set the variable `transformerFactoryClass` to `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`. See the snapshot below.

```java
final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(uri);
webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

try {
    logger.debug("Getting class for name: {}", transformerFactoryClass);
    final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(transformerFactoryClass);
    Assert.isAssignable(TransformerFactory.class, clazz, "Must be instance of Class<? extends TransformerFactory>");
    webServiceTemplate.setTransformerFactoryClass((Class<? extends TransformerFactory>) clazz);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    logger.error("Unable to get class for name: {}", transformerFactoryClass);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
}
```